# UIActivityViewController get selected item

Tags: ios, iphone, delegates, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

is there any way to get the selected item in UIActivityViewController.

I want to have different messages for Facebook, Twitter and Email, so that I can customise my message according to selection.

Thank you

Comment: put tree action for facebook,twitter,email and call separately with UIActivityViwecontroler. Else set tag for each selected and check which tag selected item called in single Action and set message according to your need

Comment: it would to great help for me if you can share sample code.

Comment: you have different Button for Facebook, twitter and email?

Comment: No, Single button for sharing.

Comment: Please check here it is very nice example: http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2012/10/objective-c-custom-uiactivityviewcontroller-icons-text/ you need to create custom one for different data sharing for different activity.

Comment: else I suggest to use `SLComposeViewController` for facebook and twitter and for mail use `MFMailComposeViewController`